# PHP if statement - can I use it like this?

Tags: php

```
if(!isset($_GET['set']) && (($_GET['set'] != 'on') || ($_GET['set'] != 'off'))){
    header('Location: http://google.com');
    exit;
}
```

What I want to check is if set has not set and value is not on or off. Is this right or is there any other way?

Comment: If `$_GET['set']` is not set, there is no need to check if it is not equal to `'off'` or `'on'`.

Comment: That looks fine to me at first glance.

Comment: Just remember that if it's tricky to follow the logic now when you look at it, it's going to be even harder when you come back to it six months from now. Breaking it up into separate lines will make it much more maintainable.

Comment: *"Can I use it like this"* Have you tried? Did it work? Did it do as you expected? If so, you can apparently use it like this. If not, you can't.

Comment: No, it's not right. There are multiple logic problems with it. First `!isset` implies it's not set, and therefore the only way for that to be true will error the rest of it. Second, `!='on' || !='off'` will **always** be true. Therefore, your code will be reduced to `!isset($_GET['set'])`. And that's obviously not what you intended. So no, it's not ok...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, all you need is this:

```
if(!isset($_GET['set'])){
    header('Location: http://google.com');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: What if it's set and is not 'on' or 'off' ?

Comment: Sorry, but it's in the question... ;)

Comment: Well question was actually clear about that part: "What I want to check is if set has not set and value is not on or off", so the !isset() is actually not asked about in specific if you name that.

Comment: Ah fair enough - the answer remains though, no condition is needed after the `!isset` returns true.

Comment: With the code, as-is, you're absolutely correct, but it doesn't reflect what he's trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

You swapped `&&` and `||`:

```
if (!isset($_GET['set']) || (($_GET['set'] != 'on') && ($_GET['set'] != 'off'))){
    header('Location: http://google.com');
    exit;
}
```

Those errors are not easy to spot. It can help to divide the problem:

```
$isSet   = isset($_GET['set']);
$isOn    = $isSet && $_GET['set'] === 'on';
$isOff   = $isSet && $_GET['set'] === 'off';
$isOnOff = $isOn || $isOff;

if (!$isOnOff) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check beyond `!isset()`. If `$_GET['set']` is not set, it won't have any values.

```
if(!isset($_GET['set'])) {
    header('Location: http://google.com');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. I was an idiot. I didn't see this if is not set part.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to define your variables to avoid `Notice: Undefined variable:`  since you sill want to make sure  `$_GET['set']` must be either `on` or `off` ;

```
$_GET['set'] = isset($_GET['set']) ? $_GET['set'] : null ;

if(!($_GET['set'] == "on" || $_GET['set'] == "off")){
    header('Location: http://google.com');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: That if statement will always be true. Because both `!= 'on'` and `!= 'off'` can **never** be `false` at the same time. Therefore, your if becomes a tautology...

Comment: You could rely on short circuiting (eg: `if (isset($var) && ...)`) to avoid undefined variable notices.

Comment: @ircmaxell The statement would be true if `$_GET['set'] = "on";` or `$_GET['set'] = "off";` see http://codepad.viper-7.com/Ofve8X

Comment: @Baba: It's **always** true. http://codepad.viper-7.com/BrAdzI

Comment: @Baba You can change it to `'banana'` and it will still be true.

Comment: @ircmaxell i see your point .. thanks ...... would edit right away

Comment: @ircmaxwell thanks for the tip see updated logic http://codepad.viper-7.com/Zr28qF

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(!isset($_GET['set']))?header('Location: http://google.com'): exit;
```